# How to connect with a vpn connection without any prompt in windows 8

Tags: windows-7, connection, windows-8, shortcut, keyboard-shortcuts

In windows 7 , we can define a hotkey for connect to internet via VPN connection immediately without any prompt, through these Steps:

1. Create shortcut for VPN connection for example in Desktop.
2. Define a hotkey for that shortcut
3. In VPN properties >> options TAB >> dialing options >> uncheck this checkbox : "prompt for name and password..."

This checkbox not exist in windows 8

so we cant define in Windows 8 like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache the credentials while creating the VPN connection:

Charms bar / Search / Type vpn / Click Settings / Click Set up a virtual private network (VPN) connection:

Click Remember my credentials to save your credentials on the first successful connection attempt:

[image]

Now you can click on Charms bar / Settings / Network icon / Click the name of the VPN connection / Click the Connect button:

You can create a shortcut to the connection by going to the Charms bar / Search / Type vpn / Click Settings / Click View Network Connections, or by going to Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network Connections:

If you want a shortcut that automatically dials the VPN connection for you (which the one above won't), follow the steps mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/521348/how-to-connect-with-a-vpn-connection-without-any-prompt-in-windows-8)